# Href onclick Function Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In a bootstrap container...i used this code:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a href="" class="active" id="loginFormLink" onclick="LoginFormOpen()"> Login </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a href="" id="registerFormLink" onclick="alert('here....')"> Register </a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

the onclick alert funtion works on register but the function i am trying to execute in onclick for login does not....why?...

this is the

```
function LoginFormOpen()
{
    alert('Testing....');
    /*$('#loginForm').delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $('#registerForm').fadeOut(100);
    $('#registerFormLink').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
    });*/
}
```

Comment: Works just fine for me

Comment: Here for me too...even though I would recommend you to use jQuery if you tagged your question with it and used pure Javascript instead, excepting the commented code.

Comment: you guys are saying that when you click the "Login" link....you get the "tesing...." alert pop up too......because i dont.

Answer (score 1):

This might happening because you are using `onclick` attribute as well as `href` attribute. If you are using `onclik` you don't need to put `href`. That's why might page is redirecting to blank page.

I think you are usning `href` attribute because of that hand sign, so please follow the below code::

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

SO, Your final html should be like this::

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active" id="loginFormLink" onclick="LoginFormOpen()"> Login </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="registerFormLink" onclick="alert('here....');"> Register </a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope...the function one still does not execute, only simple alert works...i think i will use a button instead for for login and register form...thank you....href links might work differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's all matter of scope. If you define the function inside the `$(document).ready` scope it can be called only inside it. Move the function outside the `$(document).ready` and it should work.

So if you have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function LoginFormOpen() {
    alert('Testing....');
    /*$('#loginForm').delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $('#registerForm').fadeOut(100);
    $('#registerFormLink').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
    });*/
  }
});
```

It really should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});

function LoginFormOpen() {
  alert('Testing....');
  /*$('#loginForm').delay(100).fadeIn(100);
  $('#registerForm').fadeOut(100);
  $('#registerFormLink').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
  });*/
}
```